# Is it possible to disable strict mode per user

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a host that I use for running some data import scripts. These are pretty old / legacy scripts that aren't important to anything and aren't sensitive. The host recently upgraded mariaDB and now it's in strict mode, such that my old scripts that used work fine are failing when they try to insert empty strings against a column defined for `int` values.

I've asked the host to disable strict mode so that I can continue without making a bunch of changes to my scripts that always worked fine-- they say they need to think it over to "assess the impact on other customers".

Am I wrong to think that if they were running my user as its own user / schema, they wouldn't need to impact any other customer? While I take their point that using strict mode is a best practice, it seems like they should have more separation between customer environments so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: A model could be like [this](https://openquery.com.au/blog/optimising-multithreaded-replication) that uses `init_connect` and a stored procedure to set a session variable.

Comment: Imho each user must set his environment as he need by himself. The host must only provide instruments/permissions for that. So you must simply add proper `SET sql_mode` init command to your connection properties.